# How to modify options being passed to ld , without recompiling gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, solaris

I'm trying to compile shared library on solaris 2.7 using gcc 3.4.6 and 
which is linking to a statically linked c .a and .o files.
Please note that it is using Sun ld from path "/usr/ccs/bin/ld"

At linking time i got a long list of symbols and following error

```
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then i tried to build it passing  -z textoff option to ld. but i'm getting follwing error

```
ld: fatal: option -ztextoff and -ztext are incompatible

ld: fatal: Flags processing errors
```

Is there any other way where i don't need to recompile gcc and still modify the options getting passed to ld.

Comment: I think, i just now got one way.
gcc normally uses "specs" file to convert options passed to gcc generic interface to  option for underlying assembler and linker.  

in gcc 3.4.6 there is an option we can pass our own "specs" file.

So what i did is, i copied the original file and modified it , not to pass -ztext option to sun linker.

I doubt this to be the correct way, but it solved the purpose for now and i can continue with my work, till the time i got the correctly configured gcc.

Query is still open for the better or correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors are the result of linking position-dependent code into a shared library. Such code will result in the library not being shareable, and thus wasting RAM.

If you can rebuild all the objects you are trying to link into the shared library, the simplest (and most correct) solution is to rebuild all of them with `-fPIC` flag.

However, sometimes you really must link non-PIC object code which you can't rebuild into a shared library, and therefore you need to get rid of the `-ztext` option. To do that, add `-mimpure-text` option to your link line.

Comment: Thanks!! 
Yeah I'm in one such situation, and i have to use this statically linked code within a shared object.

Yes "-mimpure-text" option worked for me.

I checked and found out that even in the spec file , i have modified  this parameter, but using this -mimpure-text is the right way.

Thanks again, it solves one of my long pending issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the **ld** executable from the command line (not via gcc) - you can then pass it whatever parameters you want. I don't think that will solve your underlying problems though - you might want to post a question about them.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks , I'll try that. might be little difficult as project has good no of files. 
So is there a way i can modify options passed by gcc so that i need not to call ld manually. ( of-course without recompiling it )
Sorry but i didn't get your point "underlying problem"

Comment: This is a terrible idea, and almost never the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using make or some other build system to invoke the compiler?

If you change the options in the build system to specifically use the linker during the link phase rather than using the compiler.

Step 1: Find flags passed by gcc

Add the -v flag. It makes gcc verbose.

> CXXFLAGS += -v

Step 2: Modify the link stage to explicitly use the tool that gcc was invoking.

Comment: We are using gnu make.
Do you mean in the Makefile i should us ld and pass object files directly with appropriate linker options?
Can be done but i have to prepare that option list required to be passed to ld very carefully.


Is there an easy way by which i can find out what all options are being passed to ld by gcc.
So that when i call ld manually, i can pass all of them removing -ztext option.
I try using -v option but that prints arguments passed to collect2 utility.

As i mentioned in comments to my question, modifying the specs file seems to be easier in this particular case.

Comment: @Martin  as mentioned in my comment
 I did the same passed -v flag to gcc , and it gives me arguments passed to collect2 utility and not to the underlying sun linker.



What's your opinion regarding using the specialized specs file to achieve this?

Comment: I would be more inclined to use the coolect2 utility rather than building your own specs files.

Comment: Invoking underlying linker directly is a terrible idea. It leads to a link line which will likely be incorrect for the next version if GCC or the new version of the OS. Just don't do it(TM).